# Converter string em array junto com delimitador

Tags: php, array

Estou a separar uma string em array caso haja uma certa preposição nela ('com', 'para', 'por'), porém quero o retorno dessa string contendo também o delimitador, ou seja, a preposição.

Utilizando o preg_split e explode, eu tenho o mesmo resultado e não satisfatório:

```
$string = 'Programação com Stackoverflow';

$resultado = explode('com', $string);
$resultado2 = preg_split('/com|para|by|por/', $string);

Array
(
    [0] => Programação 
    [1] =>  Stackoverflow
)
```

O resultado esperado para o que procuro:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Programação 
    [1] => com
    [2] =>  Stackoverflow
)
```

Comment: Você quer que, quando contenha `com`, "exploda" a string? Não terias que verificar primeiro a palavra `com|para|by|por` com `preg_match`?

Comment: Sim, @WallaceMaxters. E preciso da preposição junto do resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_split('/(com|para|by|por)/', $string, false, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
```

Answer (score 1):

Não seria algo assim?

```
$regex = 'Filme com pipoca';

if (preg_match('/com|by|para|por/u', $string)) {
    $array = preg_split('/\s+/u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

Resultado:

> ['Filme', 'com', 'Pipoca']

Utilizamos uma expressão para verificar se  existe algum dos valores na string e, em seguida, quando esse valor é achado, a string é divida pelos espaços, a fim de separar as palavras em um array.

Creio que é uma boa ideia utilizar o `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`, para não retornar nenhum valor vazio.

Comment: Porém, caso tenha algo mais na palavra, ele também retorna como uma chave no array. Ex: 'Stackoverflow por Wallace Maxter' ele retorna:  `['Stackoverflow', 'por', 'Wallace', 'Maxter']` quando deveria ser apenas: `'[Stackoverflow', 'por', 'Wallace Maxter']`

Comment: Entendi. Você quer que `por` entre no processamento de divisão da expressão regular e, ao mesmo tempo, quer que ele "continue" no `array`.

Comment: Exatamente, @Wallace. Eu receberei uma string e a separarei em 3 partes, consegui da seguinte maneira: preg_split('/(com|para|by|por)/', $string, false, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );

Comment: Legal. Agora entendi pra que serve o tal do `Delim Capture`

Comment: Vou adicionar na resposta :)

Comment: Não adicionou, @Wallace.